# Running an API on Standalone JavaScript program

Tags: javascript, api

I am working on a standalone JavaScript program in which I take Kimono Lab's FIFA World Cup 2014 [API](http://www.kimonolabs.com/worldcup/explorer), and by the World Cup Groups, I display the teams and their record.

For elaboration, I will run this on the command line, and the sole argument the program will take in is a letter from A-H, which resemble the world cup groups. Then, from there, the program will return the teams, and display their record.

So, in light of that, I have looked on this website, and other places to learn how to use the API on a standalone JavaScript program, but I have not seen anything that helps me with what I need. So, how can I run the API on a standalone program?

I am not asking for all my code to be done. I just want to know how to use the API. I am a beginner in JavaScript, so please bear with me.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Asking how to use an API isn't really the purpose of stackoverflow unless you have a specific question about that api.

Comment: I was not aware of that. I will keep that in mind next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Generally Javascript is a client-run language. Meaning that you need to run the code inside a web browser.

That said you can use [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) to run Javascript code on the command line.

If you're wanting to write command line utilities, then I'd highly recommend using a language like Python instead of Javascript.

Comment: Well, I do use NodeJS, so I know about that.